# what does <_io.TextIOWrapper name='canc.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> error mean in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to open a CSV file in python, but I am getting this error again and again. This is my code:

```
import csv
with open("canc.csv","r") as csvFile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
  data = []
  for row in reader:
     if len(row) !=0:
        data = data + [row]
csvFile.close()
print(csvFile)`
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's the contents of `csvFile` that you are `print`ing

Comment: Try `print(data)` instead

Comment: Thanks, it has helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `csvFile` is a file, not the contents, which you read into `data`

In fact, as print has told you it's an TExtIOWrapper, with a name, mode and encoding: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='canc.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

If you want to see the data in the file, simply use

```
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want open csvFile in yor program try writing print(csvFile.read()